# How to call a java script on deactivation of wordpress plugin

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress

I want to call a js file which have a ready function to call my api. My Code is..

```
<?php
.
. // rest all code.................................
.
.

/* Runs on plugin deactivation*/
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'Pushbiz_remove' );

function Pushbiz_remove() {
/* Deletes the database field */

delete_option('PushBIZ_firstCreation');
delete_option('VarPushBIZapikey');
delete_option('PushBIZRegUrl');

wp_register_script( 'DeactivationJS', plugins_url( '/admin/js/deactivation.js', __FILE__ ));
wp_enqueue_script( 'DeactivationJS' );

}
?>
```

I am unable to call deactivation.js on on the deactivation of plugin. How can i call this java script on the event of deactivation.

Answer (score 0):

Can you please check below code?

```
/* Runs on plugin deactivation*/
register_deactivation_hook( __FILE__, 'Pushbiz_remove' );

function Pushbiz_remove() {
/* Deletes the database field */

    delete_option('PushBIZ_firstCreation');
    delete_option('VarPushBIZapikey');
    delete_option('PushBIZRegUrl');

    add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'DeactivationJS_scripts' );
}
function DeactivationJS_scripts(){  
    wp_enqueue_script( 'DeactivationJS', plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ ) .'/admin/js/deactivation.js');  
}
```